# How did the author get from the first to the second line of the formula?

Tags: statistics

[image]

Sorry I am a complete noob. Looking into statistical learning

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to a bunch of well-known simplifications of things, but the big thing is that since the Expectation is a linear operator, you can do this:

$\begin{align}
E\left[\left(f(X) + \epsilon - \hat{f}(x)\right)^2\right] & = E\left[\left(f(X) - \hat{f}(X)\right)^2 + \epsilon^2 - 2\left(f(X)-\hat{f}(X)\right)\epsilon\right]\\
& = \left(f(X) - \hat{f}(X)\right)^2 - 2\left(f(X) - \hat{f}(X)\right)E(\epsilon) + E(\epsilon^2) \\
& = \left(f(X) - \hat{f}(X)\right)^2 + Var(\epsilon)\end{align}$

Where in the last line I assume that $\epsilon$ is some kind of unbiased error term so that $E(\epsilon) = 0$ and hence $E(\epsilon^2) = E((\epsilon - E(\epsilon))^2) = Var(\epsilon)$.

Comment: ahhh I see it now! thank you so much.